# foreach nested class

Tags: c#

Tengo un código con clases publicas que necesito leer.

El problema es que cuando intento hacer un foreach obtengo los valores de los public string pero no de las subclases(datosIdentificativos).

Necesito obtener los valores de las sublcases:

> ```
> datosIdentificativos 
>   _id  
>        datosPersonaFisica :
>            primerApellido  
>            fechaNacimiento
> ```

¿Cómo puedo hacer?

Adjunto código:

```
                foreach (Constructores_WMODH_Response.Result item  in root.data.results)
                {
                    Type tType = item.GetType();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in tType.GetProperties())
                    {
                        string ColumnaNombre = prop.Name;
                        object ColumnaValor = prop.GetValue(item, null);
                    }

                }
```

Mis clases son:

```
    public class Result
    {
        public string _id { get; set; }
        public DatosIdentificativos datosIdentificativos { get; set; }

    }
    public class DatosIdentificativos
    {
        public DatosPersonaFisica datosPersonaFisica { get; set; }
        public string numeroDocumentoIdentidad { get; set; }
        public string tipoDocumentoIdentidad { get; set; }
    }

    public class DatosPersonaFisica
    {
        public string primerApellido { get; set; }
        public DateTime? fechaNacimiento { get; set; }
    }
```

Aquí hay una captura de pantalla de mi depurador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: object ColumnaValor = prop.GetValue(item, null); si prop es de tipo complejo, no quiere el valor del prop y no el de item, o tal vez quiere otro foreach (o metodo) para devolver las properidades de prop?

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal seria otro foreach dentro de prop para obtener los nested classes.
Pero no soy capaz de hacerlo.

ahora mismo estoy haciendo lo siguiente pero no soy capaz de crear una lista con los subclases

```
  foreach (Constructores_WMODH_Response.Result item  in root.data.results)
                {

                    Type tType = item.GetType();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in tType.GetProperties())
                    {
                        string Col_Nombre = prop.Name;
                        object Col_Val;

                        
                        if (prop.PropertyType.Name.ToLower().Contains("datosidentificativos"))
                        {

                            var list = prop.GetValue(item, null);
                            var list2 = (Constructores_WMODH_Response.DatosIdentificativosIEnumerable)prop.GetValue(item, null);

                            foreach (var item_list in list2) 
                            {
                                string aa = item_list.ToString();
                                Col_Val = item_list.ToString();
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Col_Val = prop.GetValue(item, null);
                        }

                        

                    }
                }
```